# Phone toggle menu disappear when on mobile devices

Tags: wordpress

The phone toggle menu has disappeared when using on mobile only. Suspected Plugin conflict. Steps taken so far:

1. Switched plugins on/off and then rechecked website to see if toggle menu in header appeared (did not work)
2. Rollback all plugins that had been automatically updated since the problem first arose ( plugins rolled back to previous versions when issue did not occur) - did not work.

N.B cache cleared every time an action was taken.

Any advice and guidance would be awesome!

Thank you

[www.sfe-academy.co.uk](http://www.sfe-academy.co.uk)